# Can I make swagger-php use arrays on the query string?

Tags: php, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-php

I use Swagger-php. When I define a parameter that's on the query string it can be an array. But from what I can see, it doesn't support this kind of querystring:

```
https://api.domain.tld/v1/objects?q[]=1&q[]=5&q[]=12
```

I believe this would be set [in the `collectionFormat`field](http://swagger.io/specification/#parameterObject) if possible. Currently I've just been using `pipes`, but I want to use the above format, and have Swagger-UI reflect this, too. However, I read [this github issue](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/682) which has left me wondering if this is actually possible and I've just missed it?

An example of my Swagger-PHP definition:

```
/**
*     @SWG\Parameter(
*         name="ids",
*         in="query",
*         description="A list of IDs (separated by pipes) to filter the Returns",
*         required=false,
*         type="array",
*         @SWG\Items(
*             type="integer",
*             format="int32"
*         ),
*         collectionFormat="pipes"
*     )
*/
```

Which results in the following JSON:

```
"parameters": {
    "ids": {
        "name": "ids",
        "in": "query",
        "description": "A list of IDs (separated by pipes) to filter the Returns",
        "required": false,
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
        },
        "collectionFormat": "pipes"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its now possible to do this without [] hack of most liked answer.
Use the deepObject style.

```
 name: q
 style: deepObject
 schema:
   type: array
   items:
     type: string
```

This will generate an url like following:
q[0]=string1&q[1]=string2

Comment: `deepObject` style is not defined for arrays, it's only [defined for objects](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.1.0.md#style-values). So this answer is not OpenAPI-compliant. As of March 2021 / OpenAPI 3.1, the correct solution is still to use a parameter named `q[]`, like shown in Ima's answer.

Answer (score 14):

```
/**
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="q[]",
 *         in="query",
 *         description="A list of IDs (separated by new lines) to filter the Returns",
 *         required=false,
 *         type="array",
 *         collectionFormat="multi",
 *         uniqueItems=true,
 *     )
 */
```

This will result in something similiar to this

```
{
    "name": "q[]",
    "in": "query",
    "description": "type",
    "required": false,
    "type": "array",
    "collectionFormat": "multi",
    "uniqueItems": true
}
```

[image: Resulting image]

Comment: This should be the answer. I have spent a few hours searching for answers and as the current answer says, only multi, csv, ssv or tsv are accepted, but adding brackets to the name works with multi. There's no website, blog, or documentation for this case except this comment.

Comment: Check following for solution without [] hack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59034737/2814058

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't already I'd suggest trying the following:

```
*      @OA\Parameter(
*          name="category[]",
*          description="array of category numbers",
*          in="query",     
*          @OA\Schema( 
*              type="array", 
*              @OA\Items(type="enum", enum={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}),
*              example={1,2} 
*          )
*      ),
```

I modified this to fit my use-case:

```
*    @OA\Parameter(
*      name="things[]",
*      in="query",
*      description="A list of things.",
*      required=false,
*      @OA\Schema(
*        type="array",
*        @OA\Items(type="integer")
*      )
*    ),
```

Source: https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/issues/612#issue-380202012

Answer (score 2):

Please go through this; this is work for me

```
 /**
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="id[]",
 *         in="query",
 *         description="A list of IDs (separated by new lines) to filter 
            the Returns",
 *         required=false,
 *         type="array",
 *         collectionFormat="multi",
 *        @SWG\Items(
 *             type="integer",
 *             format="int32"
 *         ),
 *         uniqueItems=true,
 *     )
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to get *exactly* the URL you provide (`https://api.domain.tld/v1/objects?q[]=1&q[]=5&q[]=12`) for an array query parameter.

Assuming that you want to define a 1 dimension array query parameter (the github issue you're refering to concerns multi-dimensional arrays), here's what the current OpenAPI (fka. Swagger) Specification can propose:

- If you use an array with a collection format like `pipes` (you can also use `csv`, `ssv` or `tsv` to get different separators) the URL will look like this:

  ```
  https://api.domain.tld/v1/objects?q=1|5|12
  ```

  But this is not the syntax you're looking for: all array items are defined in a single `q` query parameter.
- Fortunately, there is another collection format `multi` allowing to define each array's item in its own `q` parameter, with this one you can *almost* get what you want minus the `[]`:

  ```
  https://api.domain.tld/v1/objects?q=1&q=5&q=12
  ```

You can read more about this in this [OpenAPI (fka. Swagger) tutorial](http://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-5-advanced-input-and-output-modeling/) (disclosure: I wrote it) and in the [specification itself (ParameterObject description)](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameterObject)

Comment: Thanks @Arnaud. I considered `multi` but with PHP you would get just the last value unfortunately, so I've decided to go with `pipes` after all. Nice tutorial by the way :)

Comment: Check following how to do it without a hack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59034737/2814058

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: im using **SwaggerUI**, but this might work for you as well.

I was also wondering about this for some time, but i decided to go through the js code and see if i can change/fix it there and i noticed these few lines of code:

```
if (type === 'brackets' || type === 'multi') {
    var bracket = type === 'brackets' ? '[]' : ''
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {encoded += '&';}

        encoded += this.encodeQueryParam(name) + bracket + '=' + this.encodeQueryParam(value[i]);
    }
}
```

So it seems there is a **collectionFormat** 'brackets' that was **not defined in the OpenAPI v2** specification. Tried it out and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works fine: [See the ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2lHF.png)

'"parameters": [

```
      {

        "name": "fav",

        "description": "Enter ids of Favoruite",

        "in": "formData",

        "type": "array",

        "items": {

          "type": "integer",

          "format": "int32"

        },

        "paramType": "form",

        "required": true

      }],'
```