# swagger-php How to use arrays in swagger via formData

Tags: php, arrays, swagger, swagger-php

I want to receive in my api via $_POST (formData) an array like this:

```
answers[458]=hi&answers[90]=hello
```

.

```
array(1) {
  ["answer"]=>
  array(2) {
    [458]=>
    string(2) "hi"
    [90]=>
    string(5) "hello"
  }
}
```

When i use postman i can do this so for my code there is no problem, but now i want to use swagger and thats where i cant get it to work.

i've tried

```
/**
 * @SWG\Post(
 *   path="/sec/answer",
 *   summary="location",
 *   tags={"question"},
 *   @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="answer",
 *         in="formData",
 *         description="",
 *         type="array",
 *         @SWG\Items(
 *             type="string"
 *         )
 *   ),
 *   @SWG\Response(
 *     response=200,
 *     description="array"
 *   )
 * )
 */
```

But the problem with this is that i get a field with multiple lines in swagger and when i fill this with:
hi
hello

this results in the following request:

```
'answer=hi&answer=hello'
```

with this result:

```
array(1) {
  ["answer"]=>
  string(5) "hello"
}
```

i know that with this option i cant receive an array with a variable key(because i cant fill in the key), but as far as i can see this isn't even an array swagger sends a wrong request with overruling parameters.

What to do? I hope someone can help me

Ps.
i have also tried an array within an array but this has the same result

Comment: What is the request body when you use Postman?

Comment: "answers[458]=hi&answers[90]=hello"

Comment: What if you change `name="answer"` to `name="answer[]"`?

Comment: Tried that, you'll get url encoded characters for []

Comment: there is a similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878018/can-i-make-swagger-php-use-arrays-on-the-query-string  , but it seems that there is no answer

Comment: have you found any resolution for this one?

Comment: Sorry, no i think it's not possible (at least at that time)..